# Why does copy.come uses A LOT of CPU?

Tags: cloud-storage

I've noticed several times on Windows 8, and now on OSX 10.7 too, that the [copy.com](http://copy.com/) app (a dropbox clone) sometimes starts using a lot of CPU, usually over 100%.

This happens suddenly for no apparent reason, i.e. doesn't happen right after I put some files in his folder.

Is this a known behaviour with a convincing explaination?

Comment: What exactly does this program do.  How exactly does OSX run a Windows extension?

Comment: It doesn't. It's called exactly [copy.com](http://copy.com/), and it's basically a dropbox clone.

Answer (score 0):

The way the program tells if it needs to upload a file or not is by hashing the file and comparing it to the file hash that is on the server. I have never used copy.com but in dropbox it calls this process "indexing", that is the likely activity the program is doing when using 100% CPU.

Comment: But as I said, it did it spontaneously, _not_ after I put some new file in the folder.